# Converting Legacy Project to Today's Technologies

Tags: asp.net, .net, stored-procedures, asp-classic, converters

I'm working on an old Classic ASP Project and this project connected to MSSQL Database.(Database includes lots of Stored Procedures like maybe 400+). I want to update this project up to ASP.Net 6.0 and want to use Entity Framework 6.0. Is it possible or am ı dreaming?

I'm looking for this problem solution and ı found this; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1246313/about-the-asp-to-asp-net-v1-x-migration-assistant

Microsoft's ASP to ASP.NET tutorial link is no longer available. and ı found a video about this; https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/shows/asp-net-site-videos/migrating-from-classic-asp-to-aspnet

but did not satisfy. Please help me, ı don't want to write all of them from the scratch. I don't have any time and any budget for this.

Comment: Stored procedures can do a lot more than just read or write data. All 400 of them must be checked for that fact alone. And if there is logic in them that has to be then done in the project itself.

Comment: It already contains logic that should be included in the project, so I think it should be moved into the project.

Comment: Is it possible? Everything is possible with enough time and resources, you need to make this question less vague. Or are you just looking for a one-word answer, in which case the answer is "Yes".

Comment: The one good thing is it seems that the original dev was thoughtful and made procedures you can hook into after verifying, versus putting the MYSQL sstatements into a string on the front end pages and having to build the procedures for each statement yourself.

Comment: For such big projects, either your client have a 8k-15k budget (I'm not kidding) to plan a migration + 8months for it, or you should maintain the current app using the Classic ASP platform. You can go very far if you use good patterns (aka "not-the-ones-you-find-in-microsoft-dated-examples"), and if you rely on external Component libraries such as Persits, Chilkat, etc. I'm still maintaining huge legacy Classic ASP extranets, websites and intranets for big clients, and it's less costly and far more less risky than a complete rewrite to another platform.